# in which way calcium promotes cell division

Tags: chemical-biology

I have read in bio chemistry that calcium plays an important role in the cell division but the in depth information is'nt available in the textbook and I cannot memorize any fact without a supporting fact I just want to know what is its role in the process of cell division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see its simple all you need to know is that calcium is responsible for the formation of middle lamellum which is a key structure in the cell wall formation if only karyokinesis occurs and cytokinesis fails to happen then the condition of resultant cell would become multinucleated which most plants do not have